# debug expression for seeing the content of an NSManagedObjectContext

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

How do I view the state of an NSManagedObjectContext in xcode debug?

I am trying to see/examine the processed/unprocessed object count (at the very least).

All I get at the moment is an object reference that shows me 'nothing' I can use...

Comment: Had what working? Most of the context contents is usually not in memory...

Comment: I was able to expand the context variable and look at its content.

Comment: Perhaps the current content of inserted, updated & deleted before a save?

Comment: yes. Not sure how to view this...